# "each layer" or "each layers"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Is there any difference between these two sentences? I saw both of them in the literature. which one is more formal?

> The thickness of each layer is known.
>
> The thickness of each layers is known.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [each](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/each).

Comment: There is no question of formality. "… each layers is known" is simply wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each layer is more formal by way of being correct while "each layers" is incorrect. [Each](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/each) is singular.